# OleDB / MySQL Parameter Adding

Tags: c#, mysql, oledb

I have a question about adding parameters to a command (MySQL or OleDB, I currently use both) to avoid SQL injection.

This hard coded query works absolutely fine, aside from the open vulnerability to injection;

```
var queryString = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employs WHERE em_netname = '"+username+"' AND em_password = '"+password+"'");
```

However, after modifying the query so that I add parameters rather than leave the vulnerability open, it doesn't work. This is how I do it;

```
var queryString = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employs WHERE em_netname = @username AND em_password = @password");
OleDbCommand dbfQuery = new OleDbCommand(queryString, dbfCon);
dbfQuery.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.Char).Value = username;
dbfQuery.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.Char).Value = password;
```

Could somebody please give me an explanation as to why this is not working? The first query returns 1 from count, the second returns 0 (it should return 1).

EDIT: For clarity by "doesn't work" I mean that the first statement returns a column count of 1 i.e. there is a user, the query does work. The second statement, with exactly the same username and password entered returns a 0, i.e. although a username and password combination does exist (proven by the first statement) the query is not working correctly.

EDIT 2: Entire class code posted;

```
public static bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;           
        using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                var queryString = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employs WHERE em_netname = @username AND em_password = @password");
                OleDbCommand dbfQuery = new OleDbCommand(queryString, dbfCon);
                dbfQuery.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.Char).Value = username;
                dbfQuery.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.Char).Value = password;
                MessageBox.Show("Query: " + queryString);
                int numOfColumns = Convert.ToInt32(dbfQuery.ExecuteScalar());
                MessageBox.Show(numOfColumns.ToString());
                if (numOfColumns == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? And how do you execute your queries exactly? Don't store your passwords as a plain text by the way. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: Out of context - you are storing passwords in your database?

Comment: @SonerGönül I've updated by answer for clarity.

Comment: @Serv unfortunately I have picked this project up from somebody else and yes, they were storing passwords in the database (it was written in Visual Fox Pro about 15 years ago). For now I am sticking with it but I am working on a whole new database schema.

Comment: @SonerGönül I've edited again to add the class in its entirety

Comment: You may be running into an issue where your OLEDB provider doesn't support named parameters. You may need to use positional placeholders with the ? character instead. To do so, just replace `@username` and `@password` with the ? character in the SQL query, and make sure the parameters are added to the parameter list in the correct order.

Comment: did you also try it with varchar  as oledbtype instead of char? (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) the `OleDbCommand` does not support named parameters. Try to use `?` instead.

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>   `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?`
>   Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Comment: Microsoft has a habit of changing their links. You may want to copy/paste a relevant snippet from the documentation for historical purposes.

Comment: No my friend. MSDN is quite wrong about that. This provider **does** support named parameters. It just does not _care_ the parameter names. Only care about their orders. That means you **don't have to** use `?` for every parameter with this provider.

Comment: @SonerGönül Changing to `?` instead of `@username` did indeed work in this case